# Conformance to 'X' is not covered by macro 'Y' with Swift extension macro

Tags: swift, swift-macro

With this macro:

```
// Definition:
@attached(extension, names: arbitrary)
public macro AutoDomainError() = #externalMacro(module: "...", type: "...")

// Implementation:
public struct AutoDomainErrorMacro: ExtensionMacro {
    public static func expansion(
        of node: SwiftSyntax.AttributeSyntax,
        attachedTo declaration: some SwiftSyntax.DeclGroupSyntax,
        providingExtensionsOf type: some SwiftSyntax.TypeSyntaxProtocol,
        conformingTo protocols: [SwiftSyntax.TypeSyntax],
        in context: some SwiftSyntaxMacros.MacroExpansionContext
    ) throws -> [SwiftSyntax.ExtensionDeclSyntax] {
        let extensionDecl = try ExtensionDeclSyntax("extension \(type.trimmed): FormatableDomainError") {
        }
        
        return [extensionDecl]
    }
}
```

and this code in the `main.swift` file:

```
protocol FormatableDomainError {
    
}

@AutoDomainError
enum TestError {
    case testErrorCase
}
// Code generated by the macro:
// extension TestError: FormatableDomainError { 
// }
```

I'm getting this compilation error: `Conformance to 'FormatableDomainError' is not covered by macro 'AutoDomainError'` on the code generated by the macro.

The code produced by the macro look perfectly fine to me so I don't get the error. I tried playing with the `names` and `conformances` parameters of the `@attached` macro but nothing seems to work.

Comment: You need to say `@attached(extension, conformances: FormatableDomainError)`. Surely you have tried that?

Comment: I have. Since `FormatableDomainError` is a protocol that do not exist in the Macro target, I added `protocol FormatableDomainError {}` just before the macro declaration. I still get the same error and `conformingTo` parameter of the macro when running the Unit tests is an empty array.

Comment: Well, it has to be in the same target as the one you declared your macro in. Why is it not in there?

Comment: Where I am supposed to put the protocol declaration? If it is in the file with the macro definition I get a `Cannot find type 'FormatableDomainError' in scope` in main.swift. If it is anywhere else in the target (main.swift or the macro implementation file) I get the `Cannot find...` error on the `conformances: FormatableDomainError` of the macro definition.

Comment: If you put it in the same file as `public macro AutoDomainError()` and make it public, it should work. If it still doesn't, you should show a [mcve] of the steps you took, starting from scratch.

Comment: The `public` keyword was missing! Thanks, everything work now.